# Encountering error "Non-const lvalue reference type 'node *' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'node *'

Tags: c++, linked-list, constants, nodes

I'm trying to implement a node class that reads in a text file, and stores each separate line into a node of a linked list. However, when I attempt to build it, I receive the error listed in the title.

It appears to be coming from the `getNextPointer` function used to return the pointer of the next node in the list.

`//Function Declaration

const node* getNextPtr() const;`

`//Function Definition:
void insertAfterNode(node* previous_ptr,node::dataType &newData)`

```
{
    node* insertPtr;

    insertPtr = new node;
    insertPtr->node::setData(newData);
    insertPtr->node::setNextPtr(previous_ptr->getNextPtr());
    previous_ptr->node::setNextPtr(insertPtr);

}
```

The function should insert a single node just after the pointer sent into the parameter.

Precondition: previous_ptr points to a node in a linked list.

Postcondition: new node containing the given entry has been added after the
node that previous_ptr points to.
NOTE: This function will also throw the bad_alloc error if dynamic memory is not sufficiently allocated.

I'm receiving the error from the `insertPtr->node::setNextPtr(previous_ptr->getNextPtr());` line. I know it has something to do with my const definitions. But I can't think of anywhere else to add or remove const in order to get it working. When I put const in front of previous_ptr like this: `insertPtr->node::setNextPtr(const previous_ptr->getNextPtr());` I get a more general error that just says "expected expression" from the same line, but doesn't seem to get me much closer to a successful build. I'm new to linked lists and OOP in general, so please let me know of anything important I'm overlooking. Thank you.

Comment: You haven't posted enough code. I'm guessing `setNextPtr` accepts its argument by reference (probably should accept argument by value instead)

Comment: You're correct. `setNextPtr` takes a reference parameter. It's declared in the .h as `void setNextPtr(node* &newNextPtr); `.

Comment: change it to take `node *newNextPtr`, and make sure the `setNextPtr` function does not modify `newNextPtr`

Comment: BTW the C++ standard library contains a linked list implementation, so unless you have a good reason to be reinventing the wheel, you could just use that

Comment: Thank you. I made the changes, but I'm still getting "expected expression" error on that same line. If I remove the "const" from the `setNextPtr` parameter, it gives me a ton of linker errors. I'm guessing I need to keep that in there?


>C++ standard library contains a linked list implementation
Is this inside of `<cstdlib>`?

Comment: I'll be away from my computer as I bus to my next location. But will be back as soon as I can! Thank you M.M!

Comment: If you get linker errors it means you got past this problem and there is a different problem (you didn't see the linker errors before because it doesn't try to link if there were compilation errors).